# Why do box2d bodies objects penetrate one another when linked by joint?

Tags: box2d, p5.js

## Background

I am trying to figure out at a high level why I'm getting some unexpected behavior using [b2.js](https://github.com/bobcgausa/cook-js) (a wrapper library for box2d). I'm trying to model **crystal structures of particles in a chemical system** (all represented as `b2body` rectangles) and so I thought I'd be able to link together particles using `b2Joint` **rope** objects and create a rigid lattice of individual rectangles.

When I just place the b2Body particles on screen and don't connect them, the physics of the bodies looks right. However, when I link together the units of the crystal with a `b2Joint`, the `b2Body` **boxes now are able to overlap and penetrate each other**.

I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any guidance.

## Video of the behavior

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEUN238gd6Q&feature=youtu.be

## Code from b2.js library

Here's the relevant bit of code from b2.js where joints are created:

```
function b2Joint(type, bodyA, bodyB, props) {
    var j;
    if (type=='distance') {

        // Create distance joint

    } else if (type=='pulley') {

        // Create pulley joint

    } else if (type=='wheel') {

        // Create wheel joint

    } else if (type=='rope') {

        j = new box2d.b2RopeJointDef();
        // Connection between previous and this one
       j.bodyA = bodyA.body;
       j.bodyB = bodyB.body;
       // Equilibrium length
       j.maxLength = props.separation/b2scaleFactor;
       if (props.xy != undefined) j.localAnchorA = b2scaleTo(props.xy);

    } else if (type=='revolute') {

        // Create revolute joint

    } else if (type=='mouse') {

        // Create mouse joint

    }

    j = b2world.CreateJoint(j);
    bodyA.joints.push(j);
    return bodyA.joints.length-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

box2d bodies that are linked by joints will penetrate each other when their [*collide connected*](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2Joint.h#L82) property is false. This is the default setup.

Setting the *collide connected* property to true, should enable collision processing between connected bodies so that they no longer penetrate each other.

A tutorial on box2d joints that I like and details this more is available at: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-overview .

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this tutorial! I changed this boolean and now it looks exactly as I had expected.